# How does one create a Raku Grammar programatically (dynamically)?

Tags: grammar, raku

---

Suppose grammar G has two productions …

1. S → λ
2. S → aSb

---

In Raku, how would one create this grammar programmatically (i.e., dynamically, at runtime)?

The goal is to have a Raku program create — at runtime — a Raku grammar that might be written statically as …

```
grammar Parser
  {
  token  TOP  { <S> }
  token S { '' | 'a' <S> 'b' }
  }
```

---

Given the first answer to my question, I am trying to dynamically create what would be statically written as …

```
  grammar Parser
    {
    token TOP { <S> }
    } # end grammar Parser
```

I have tried …

```
  constant Parser := Metamodel::GrammarHOW.new_type( name => 'Parser' ) ;
  Parser.^add_method('TOP', my method TOP(Parser:) { <S> }) ;
  Parser.^compose;                                                 # } 
  say Parser.HOW.^name ;
  say Parser.^methods(:local) ;
```

However, the reply is …

```
Perl6::Metamodel::GrammarHOW
(TOP)
```

… rather than the hoped-for …

```
Perl6::Metamodel::GrammarHOW
(token TOP { <S> } BUILDALL)
```

How should `add_method` be invoked to add the `TOP` **token** (and later, other **tokens** such as the `S` **token**)?

---

After more work, **I believe that I may have a solution** …

```
  constant Parser := Metamodel::GrammarHOW.new_type( name => 'Parser' ) ;
  Parser.^add_method( 'TOP', my token TOP { <S> } ) ;
  Parser.^add_method( 'S', my token S { '' | 'a' <S> 'b' } ) ;
  Parser.^compose ;
  say Parser.HOW.^name ;
  say Parser.^methods( :local ) ;
  say Parser.parse: 'aabb' ;
```

Output is …

```
Perl6::Metamodel::GrammarHOW
(token TOP { <S> } token S { '' | 'a' <S> 'b' })
∩╜óaabb∩╜ú
 S => ∩╜óaabb∩╜ú
  S => ∩╜óab∩╜ú
   S => ∩╜ó∩╜ú
```

I had coded a **static** version of `Parser` and for that **static** `Parser` similar output to that shown above had been …

```
(token TOP { <S> } token S { '' | 'a' 'a' <S> 'b' 'b' } BUILDALL)
```

I am not sure about the fact that `BUILDALL` is missing from my **dynamically** created `Parser`.  I do not understand `BUILDALL` and did not find much when searching on-line.

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the metamodel, of course. Same as there are HOWs (Higher Order Working) for every basic type, there's a [GrammarHOW](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/10c3dbb940290c67af33dfc617b2f8ce6a21df28/src/Perl6/Metamodel/GrammarHOW.nqp) for grammars. Unfortunately, there's not a whole lot of information on the metamodel; there's [this article by Masak](https://github.com/masak/strangelyconsistent-blog-posts/blob/master/extending-the-syntax-of-perl6.markdown) which mentions the GrammarHOW, and that's that. However, looking at the code, it's essentially a class; you're probably OK if you look at the [`classHOW`](https://docs.raku.org/language/mop) examples, and make methods be tokens and classes be grammars.

Metaprogramming, in general, is a subject that's not been extensively covered so far. Which is a pity.